# Search by a double asterisk glob pattern in Java behaves differently comparing to Python

Tags: java, glob

I've created the following file structure (that seems to be a gold standard when discussing glob pattern matching):

```
Tests
│─── HelloWorld.java
│
└── ui
    │── HelloWorld.java
    │
    └── feature1
        │── HelloWorld.java
```

I'm using the following java code:

```java
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + "Tests/**/*.java");
        Path base = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath();
        Files.walk(base).forEach((path) -> {
            path = base.relativize(path);
            if (pathMatcher.matches(path)) {
                System.out.println(path);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It finds only 2 files out of 3:

```
Tests\ui\feature1\HelloWorld.java
Tests\ui\HelloWorld.java
```

And does not find this one:

```
Tests/HelloWorld.java
```

I also tried this in Python:

```python
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('Tests/**/*.java', recursive=True)
['Tests\\HelloWorld.java', 'Tests\\ui\\HelloWorld.java', 'Tests\\ui\\feature1\\HelloWorld.java']
```

So the questions are:

1. Why do results differ in Java and Python?
2. How can I modify the Java code to include `Tests/HelloWorld.java` entry using **the same** `Tests/**/*.java` pattern?

Comment: Is the current working dir (i.e `Paths.get(".")`) the same for Java and Python?

Comment: yes, the current working dir is the same

Comment: Ok, try the recursive matcher marker before the dir like `glob:**/chapter1/*.java`

Comment: `"glob:**/*.java"` works as expected. but this does not answer my question

Comment: `"glob:" + "/Tests/**/*.java"`?

Comment: @JoopEggen that doesn't work at all. Doesn't match a single file

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I meant an absolute path with preceding slash, so the current working directory does not influence the search. Because that was my conjecture for the cause. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In short:

1. The python code uses handles `/**/` as zero or more folders, while java  handles it as at least one folder. You could argue for both interpretations, but that is just how it is.
2. the java regex that would match all 3 files is: `Tests/**.java` as in java ** matches any char, no matter if it's a file or directory.
3. I would not suggest changing the way java or python handles these patterns. Better have a configuration file that has both patterns, and the application decides which version it needs. Or if you really want to input a python pattern into a java application, use some converter that just replaces `**/` with `**`.

```java
String pyGlob = "Tests/**/*.java";
String javaGlob = pyGlob.replaceAll("\\*\\*/","**");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + "Tests/**.java");
        Path base = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath();
        Files.walk(base).forEach((path) -> {
            path = base.relativize(path);
            if (pathMatcher.matches(path)) {
                System.out.println(path);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can find details and examples in [Class FileSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) please refer to `getPathMatcher` section

> /home/*/*   Matches /home/gus/data on UNIX platforms

> /home/**    Matches /home/gus and /home/gus/data on UNIX platforms

> The * character matches zero or more characters of a name component
> without crossing directory boundaries.
>
> - The ** characters matches zero or more characters crossing directory    boundaries.
> - The ? character matches exactly one character of a name component.
> - The backslash character () is used to escape characters that would otherwise be interpreted as special characters. The expression \
>   matches a single backslash and "{" matches a left brace for example.
> - The [ ] characters are a bracket expression that match a single character of a name component out of a set of characters. For example,
>   [abc] matches "a", "b", or "c". The hyphen (-) may be used to specify
>   a range so [a-z] specifies a range that matches from "a" to "z"
>   (inclusive). These forms can be mixed so [abce-g] matches "a", "b",
>   "c", "e", "f" or "g". If the character after the [ is a ! then it is
>   used for negation so [!a-c] matches any character except "a", "b", or
>   "c".
> - Within a bracket expression the *, ? and \ characters match themselves. The (-) character matches itself if it is the first
>   character within the brackets, or the first character after the ! if
>   negating.
> - The { } characters are a group of subpatterns, where the group matches if any subpattern in the group matches. The "," character is
>   used to separate the subpatterns. Groups cannot be nested.
> - Leading period/dot characters in file name are treated as regular characters in match operations. For example, the "*" glob pattern
>   matches file name ".login". The Files.isHidden(java.nio.file.Path)
>   method may be used to test whether a file is considered hidden.
> - All other characters match themselves in an implementation dependent manner. This includes characters representing any
>   name-separators.
> - The matching of root components is highly implementation-dependent and is not specified.

Comment: this works as expected and returns all the 3 entries.
But that doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: Just answered about needed modification part.

Comment: well, I mean how can I modify Java code to make it work with the original pattern

Comment: Please refer to documentation, added link at answer

Comment: I've already looked there. Does that mean that the Java glob pattern matching differs from the implementations in Python, Node.js and Bash?

Comment: The answer is given based on this: /home/\*\* Matches /home/gus and /home/gus/data on UNIX platforms - don't know about difference

Comment: The statement `/home/** Matches /home/gus and /home/gus/data` does not answer why `/home/**/gus` does not match `/home/gus` (as it does in Python and other implementations)

Comment: Please try finding answer

Comment: I will definitely try. Please upvote the question if you want to know the answer too.

Comment: Upvoted, but I think `Tests/**/*.java` matches `/home/*/*` that only finds files in second level sub folders

Answer (score 0):

I have now two different solutions for you. One is rather simple, while the other one is more complex. Lets start with the simpler solution:

Instead of using a `PathMatcher` which works with regular expressions, we work it like python does (from my understanding). From looking at [python glob](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/glob.py), it seems to work completely different to java, in that it **does not** generate a regex but simply traverses the folder structure and matches if base ("Tests") and filename ("*.java") are matching (I am no python expert, so this might be completely wrong). It ignores everything in between.

```
String pattern = "Tests/**/*.java";
String baseP = pattern.substring(0, pattern.indexOf("**")).replace("/", "\\");
String fName = pattern.substring(pattern.lastIndexOf("/")).replace("/", "\\\\")
        .replace("*", ".*") + "$";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(fName);

Path base = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath();
Files.walk(base).forEach((path) -> {
    path = base.relativize(path);
    String pathString = path.toString();
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(pathString);
    if (pathString.startsWith(baseP) && matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Match: " + path);
    }
});
```

In the above code, we extract the base and replace `/` with `\\` (note, as this is no regex, we only want a single back-slash). Afterwards, we create a regex from the filename (here we need double back-slash to match a single back-slash in the filename). As filename, I chose everything coming after the last `/`. Then we iterate over the files and check for matches. The output is:

```
Match: Tests\HelloWorld.java
Match: Tests\ui\feature1\HelloWorld.java
Match: Tests\ui\HelloWorld.java
```

The second, more complex, solution involves overwriting how the `PathMatcher` generates the regular expression to match the path.

As the generation of the regular expression happens in classes in the `sun.nio.fs` package, we need to copy the code from the [web](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/nio/fs/Globs.java).

But first, lets look at what is happening. First of all, this is the pattern which is generated by default:

```
^Tests\\.*\\[^\\]*\.java$
```

The pattern forces 2 separators (`\`) to be present in the path.

```
^Tests          - starts with "Tests"
\\              - first required separator
.*              - any string
\\              - second required separator
[^\\]*          - match everything that is not a separator
\.              - a dot
java$           - ends with "java"
```

The secret to this is hidden in `sun/nio/fs/Globs.java` where the glob pattern is translated to a regex:

```
private static String toRegexPattern(String globPattern, boolean isDos) {
    boolean inGroup = false;
    StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder("^");

    int i = 0;
    while (i < globPattern.length()) {
        char c = globPattern.charAt(i++);
        switch (c) {
            case '\\':
                // escape special characters
                if (i == globPattern.length()) {
                    throw new PatternSyntaxException("No character to escape",
                            globPattern, i - 1);
                }
                char next = globPattern.charAt(i++);
                if (isGlobMeta(next) || isRegexMeta(next)) {
                    regex.append('\\');
                }
                regex.append(next);
                break;
            case '/':
                if (isDos) {
                    regex.append("\\\\");
                } else {
                    regex.append(c);
                }
                break;
            case '[':
                // don't match name separator in class
                if (isDos) {
                    regex.append("[[^\\\\]&&[");
                } else {
                    regex.append("[[^/]&&[");
                }
                if (next(globPattern, i) == '^') {
                    // escape the regex negation char if it appears
                    regex.append("\\^");
                    i++;
                } else {
                    // negation
                    if (next(globPattern, i) == '!') {
                        regex.append('^');
                        i++;
                    }
                    // hyphen allowed at start
                    if (next(globPattern, i) == '-') {
                        regex.append('-');
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                boolean hasRangeStart = false;
                char last = 0;
                while (i < globPattern.length()) {
                    c = globPattern.charAt(i++);
                    if (c == ']') {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (c == '/' || (isDos && c == '\\')) {
                        throw new PatternSyntaxException("Explicit 'name separator' in class",
                                globPattern, i - 1);
                    }
                    // TBD: how to specify ']' in a class?
                    if (c == '\\' || c == '[' ||
                            c == '&' && next(globPattern, i) == '&') {
                        // escape '\', '[' or "&&" for regex class
                        regex.append('\\');
                    }
                    regex.append(c);

                    if (c == '-') {
                        if (!hasRangeStart) {
                            throw new PatternSyntaxException("Invalid range",
                                    globPattern, i - 1);
                        }
                        if ((c = next(globPattern, i++)) == EOL || c == ']') {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (c < last) {
                            throw new PatternSyntaxException("Invalid range",
                                    globPattern, i - 3);
                        }
                        regex.append(c);
                        hasRangeStart = false;
                    } else {
                        hasRangeStart = true;
                        last = c;
                    }
                }
                if (c != ']') {
                    throw new PatternSyntaxException("Missing ']", globPattern, i - 1);
                }
                regex.append("]]");
                break;
            case '{':
                if (inGroup) {
                    throw new PatternSyntaxException("Cannot nest groups",
                            globPattern, i - 1);
                }
                regex.append("(?:(?:");
                inGroup = true;
                break;
            case '}':
                if (inGroup) {
                    regex.append("))");
                    inGroup = false;
                } else {
                    regex.append('}');
                }
                break;
            case ',':
                if (inGroup) {
                    regex.append(")|(?:");
                } else {
                    regex.append(',');
                }
                break;
            case '*':
                if (next(globPattern, i) == '*') {
                    // crosses directory boundaries
                    regex.append(".*");
                    i++;
                } else {
                    // within directory boundary
                    if (isDos) {
                        regex.append("[^\\\\]*");
                    } else {
                        regex.append("[^/]*");
                    }
                }
                break;
            case '?':
               if (isDos) {
                   regex.append("[^\\\\]");
               } else {
                   regex.append("[^/]");
               }
               break;

            default:
                if (isRegexMeta(c)) {
                    regex.append('\\');
                }
                regex.append(c);
        }
    }

    if (inGroup) {
        throw new PatternSyntaxException("Missing '}", globPattern, i - 1);
    }

    return regex.append('$').toString();
}
```

Specifically, the cases for `'/'` and `'*'`:

```
case '/':
    if (isDos) {
        regex.append("\\\\");
    } else {
        regex.append(c);
    }
    break;
```

and

```
case '*':
    if (next(globPattern, i) == '*') {
        // crosses directory boundaries
        regex.append(".*");
        i++;
    } else {
        // within directory boundary
        if (isDos) {
            regex.append("[^\\\\]*");
        } else {
            regex.append("[^/]*");
        }
    }
    break;
```

So, to get the same result, we need to adjust how the pattern is parsed to a regular expression, as well as write our own `PathMatcher`.

While the `PathMatcher` is as easy as (copied from [here](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsFileSystem.java#L309)):

```
new PathMatcher() {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Path path) {
        return pattern.matcher(path.toString()).matches();
    }
};
```

The syntax/pattern parser is a bit more complex.

I have decided to improve the `'*'` case a bit like this:

```
case '*':
    if (next(globPattern, i) == '*') {
        // crosses directory boundaries
        regex.append(".*");
        i++;
        // following IF is new
        if (next(globPattern, i) == '/') {
            // ignore forced path delimiter after double asterisk
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        // within directory boundary
        if (isDos) {
            regex.append("[^\\\\]*");
        } else {
            regex.append("[^/]*");
        }
    }
    break;
```

With this simple change, we skip the second forced path separator.
It does now return all the results, but I can't guarantee if it might break for other cases. Basically, it consumes the forced path delimiter following double asterisk.

The full code (most is copied and I assume windows file system):

```
class GlobPathMatcher implements PathMatcher {

    private Pattern pattern;

    public GlobPathMatcher(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = Pattern.compile(toRegexPattern(pattern.split(":")[1], true),
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Path path) {
        return pattern.matcher(path.toString()).matches();
    }

    private static final String regexMetaChars = ".^$+{[]|()";
    private static final String globMetaChars = "\\*?[{";

    private static boolean isRegexMeta(char c) {
        return regexMetaChars.indexOf(c) != -1;
    }

    private static boolean isGlobMeta(char c) {
        return globMetaChars.indexOf(c) != -1;
    }

    private static char EOL = 0; // TBD

    private static char next(String glob, int i) {
        if (i < glob.length()) {
            return glob.charAt(i);
        }
        return EOL;
    }

    private static String toRegexPattern(String globPattern, boolean isDos) {
        boolean inGroup = false;
        StringBuilder regex = new StringBuilder("^");

        int i = 0;
        while (i < globPattern.length()) {
            char c = globPattern.charAt(i++);
            switch (c) {
                case '\\':
                    // escape special characters
                    if (i == globPattern.length()) {
                        throw new PatternSyntaxException("No character to escape", globPattern,
                                i - 1);
                    }
                    char next = globPattern.charAt(i++);
                    if (isGlobMeta(next) || isRegexMeta(next)) {
                        regex.append('\\');
                    }
                    regex.append(next);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    if (isDos) {
                        regex.append("\\\\");
                    } else {
                        regex.append(c);
                    }
                    break;
                case '[':
                    // don't match name separator in class
                    if (isDos) {
                        regex.append("[[^\\\\]&&[");
                    } else {
                        regex.append("[[^/]&&[");
                    }
                    if (next(globPattern, i) == '^') {
                        // escape the regex negation char if it appears
                        regex.append("\\^");
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        // negation
                        if (next(globPattern, i) == '!') {
                            regex.append('^');
                            i++;
                        }
                        // hyphen allowed at start
                        if (next(globPattern, i) == '-') {
                            regex.append('-');
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    boolean hasRangeStart = false;
                    char last = 0;
                    while (i < globPattern.length()) {
                        c = globPattern.charAt(i++);
                        if (c == ']') {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (c == '/' || (isDos && c == '\\')) {
                            throw new PatternSyntaxException(
                                    "Explicit 'name separator' in class", globPattern, i - 1);
                        }
                        // TBD: how to specify ']' in a class?
                        if (c == '\\' || c == '[' || c == '&' && next(globPattern, i) == '&') {
                            // escape '\', '[' or "&&" for regex class
                            regex.append('\\');
                        }
                        regex.append(c);

                        if (c == '-') {
                            if (!hasRangeStart) {
                                throw new PatternSyntaxException("Invalid range", globPattern,
                                        i - 1);
                            }
                            if ((c = next(globPattern, i++)) == EOL || c == ']') {
                                break;
                            }
                            if (c < last) {
                                throw new PatternSyntaxException("Invalid range", globPattern,
                                        i - 3);
                            }
                            regex.append(c);
                            hasRangeStart = false;
                        } else {
                            hasRangeStart = true;
                            last = c;
                        }
                    }
                    if (c != ']') {
                        throw new PatternSyntaxException("Missing ']", globPattern, i - 1);
                    }
                    regex.append("]]");
                    break;
                case '{':
                    if (inGroup) {
                        throw new PatternSyntaxException("Cannot nest groups", globPattern,
                                i - 1);
                    }
                    regex.append("(?:(?:");
                    inGroup = true;
                    break;
                case '}':
                    if (inGroup) {
                        regex.append("))");
                        inGroup = false;
                    } else {
                        regex.append('}');
                    }
                    break;
                case ',':
                    if (inGroup) {
                        regex.append(")|(?:");
                    } else {
                        regex.append(',');
                    }
                    break;
                case '*':
                    if (next(globPattern, i) == '*') {
                        // crosses directory boundaries
                        regex.append(".*");
                        i++;
                        if (next(globPattern, i) == '/') {
                            // ignore forced path delimiter
                            i++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // within directory boundary
                        if (isDos) {
                            regex.append("[^\\\\]*");
                        } else {
                            regex.append("[^/]*");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case '?':
                    if (isDos) {
                        regex.append("[^\\\\]");
                    } else {
                        regex.append("[^/]");
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    if (isRegexMeta(c)) {
                        regex.append('\\');
                    }
                    regex.append(c);
            }
        }

        if (inGroup) {
            throw new PatternSyntaxException("Missing '}", globPattern, i - 1);
        }

        return regex.append('$').toString();
    }

}
```

And you use it with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PathMatcher pathMatcher = new GlobPathMatcher("glob:" + "Tests/**/*.java");
    Path base = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath();
    Files.walk(base).forEach((path) -> {
        path = base.relativize(path);
        if (pathMatcher.matches(path)) {
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to consider replacing `**/` in the Python pattern with an alternative selector in Java `{,**/}`. This then picks up both the contents of directory "Tests" and its subdirectories:

```
String glob = "Tests/**/*.java";
String java = glob.replace("**/", "{,**/}");
PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:"+java);

pathMatcher.matches(Path.of("Tests/HelloWorld.java"));     
pathMatcher.matches(Path.of("Tests/a/HelloWorld.java"));     
pathMatcher.matches(Path.of("Tests/a/b/HelloWorld.java"));
// ==> true, true, true
```